# Store that integrates with api by link (API Xtream Codes)

Tags: php, api, store

I have tested the most popular software stores but I do not find any that make the integration that I want easily!

What I need is the following, a store that can sell both physical and virtual products, in case the virtual would be iptv credits that I want to be automatically added via API (This code I know to do) when payment is confirmed ...

I need only after the payment the store send a request to my panel that will generate these credits to the informed user during the purchase!

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: Can you give me an idea where I can get this?